# Is there a GroupRenderer in ArcGIS for javaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a GroupRenderer or similar functionality in ArcGIS for JavaScript?

What I would like to do is to show PictureMarkers with a label showing an attribute on the Graphics object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unique values render does compound values
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/uniquevaluerenderer.htm
If you have a limited number of label values, I would recommend just constructing new symbol icons for each unique combination of picture marker and label.
If you have a wide variety of labels, then try rendering the layer twice. First with a text symbol then next with a picture marker symbol. Using the different position properties on the text symbol, you should be able to closely align with the picture marker.

But, it will not be perfect control. The first strategy of creating new icons is going to give you the best control on appearance even if it takes a while.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a compound renderer in the JSAPI. Furthermore, there would also have to be a compound symbol as well (and the API would have to know to render all child symbols to the GraphicsLayer).

Comment: Seems like the only way is to duplicate Graphics objects or Graphics layers.. It doesn't feel right though...